# Is it possible to use the startup.blend UI layout in older files?

Tags: customization, interface

Is there a way to open files without changing the UI layout?

Sometimes in older files the layout will be in the old 2.4x style, which can be annoying.

One way would seem to be appending everything in, but that gets tedious with having to do it over again and again for objects, materials, textures, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When loading the file from the blender file browser uncheck the **Load UI** checkbox, which is on the left hand side in the toolbar, to ignore the layout in the file to be loaded:

[image]

**Note:** that this will keep the UI of the *current file*. It may help to reopen the startup file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) to restore your default layout, and then open the file without loading the UI.

You can also go to *File> User Preferences> File* and uncheck the **Load UI** checkbox in the **Save & Load** section and save your user settings so that this is the default behaviour for blender when opening files:

[image]

In newer versions you need to click on the gear on the top right of the window to see the LoadUI option.

[image]

Comment: **FOR WINDOWS USERS** If you decide to make the change on the user preferences, you might find that blender crashes when you double click on them to open them form the desktop: The console will flash for a second and then the app will close. If that happens you might need check the Load UI back to its default position and save the preferences. To open a file with no UI you would need to open blender first, and then open the file from within the program with Load UI box unchecked.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable "Load UI" per default you can do so in the User Preferences

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> or in the Topbar *Edit >Preferences*

[image]

In Blender 2.79 and earlier this was not possible.