# 2.8 Properties Tabs all disappeared and nothing I've tried from other answers works

Tags: interface

my little boy loves Blender, but the new 2.8 release just did something odd, he can't remember doing anything but the tabs that used to propagate the right-hand side panel no longer appear when clicking the model to modify it.

See picture...

Tried scrolling, there's nothing hidden, can't find anything else relevent to 2.8 so we are missing something.

Thanks very much in advance for helping a little boy and a noob father.
[image: What on earth have we done?]

Thanks to all the help. I found a "Fix"? Although the video he's watching is exclusively in "Layout" tab mode at the top... simply switching to "Modelling" mode brings the editing properties all back - but I thought this was just a layout so haven't figured out why they are still gone. Certainly my boy has a lot my on-screen icons and properties now than the Blender guy in the video...

The video doesn't show this>??! See Pics (the update didn't do anything for this issue).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. To save other people suggesting something you've already tried, can you mention which other answers you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Don't know if it is the reason, but the last version should not be 2.80.74.

Comment: Only valid situation where tabs disappear is when there is no active object (deleted for example). Even then world tabs and render settings should always be availabe. That looks like a glitch

Comment: Fixed for now - see my workaround - although I'm not happy I understand where the tabs went? How do you mess with a layout?

Comment: Very glad to hear Blender is a family thing. Hope we get another Blender artist! And next time when you find a solution make it an **answer.**

Answer (score 2):

Zaccyboy, I had a similar problem but mine was merely that the properties icons were hidden, not missing as I note yours are.  This will not address your problem but maybe it'll help save some time for others.  I'm running BLENDER 2.82.  My icons were hidden but there is a very tiny arrow near the top of the properties menu and clicking it brings the hidden icons back.  See image 1.

Also, if you place your cursor on the boundary ( between the properties menu and whatever screen you have open next to it ) and acquire the double arrow, a left click and drag to the right brings the icons back.  See image 2.

[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 1]

Comment: It's great you found a fix but next time try to snswer **the question**

Comment: I actually did address and answer the subject line which was "Property Tabs all disappeared."  In fact, when I googled my problem I was sent right here.  Anyone having a similar problem will also be sent right here. So, although I did not solve Zaccyboy's exact problem, there will be others who will be sent right here because of the wording of the subject line.  If they had the same problem I had they will be helped and hopefully I have saved them some time.

Answer (score 2):

I spent over a day with this problem eventually taking bits from other results, putting them together, then investigating the few property tabs that I had still got I discovered that the Render tab had somehow acquired the Pin in it's top right corner. Un-pinning it brought back the rest of the property tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (blender 2.91.2) and solved it very easily. You need to find the pin in the top right side menu and click on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed for now - see my workaround - although I'm not happy I understand where the tabs went?

Basically the tabs are all there in Modelling mode on the top bar... but have disappeared from Layout mode.

Not a full answer as to why they have disappeared from Layout when they were there before, but this should get users back in the game!

Comment: You could try to disable *Load UI* for the affected project (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149545/lost-the-workspace-menu-how-to-get-it-back/149547#149547)

Answer (score 0):

I have also suffered from the same problem. As there has no good option, I use the following method.

1. Close the file.
2. Ensure *Load UI* option is unchecked when reopening file by clicking the
   right top wheel icon to get the *Load UI* option.
3. Open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i fixed it.
There is an icon where you can change the content of the view. You can change that back to properties, see screenshot

[image]

In the corner you can add also views by dragging the when the cursor becomes a crosshair.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where Lights tab on my properties editor disappeared. This was resolved by adding a new light to the scene. Then I could select my point lights and the properties would show up again, even after deleting the new light

The Properties tabs are supposed to be context-sensitive based on whatever object is selected, but it's obviously a little buggy.