# Blender 2.8 - cycles render settings problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am fairly new to Blender and started modeling a dinosaur from the course, which I bought. The course is for older version of Blender and I have 2.8. This model has multiresolution modifier and I want to bake a normal map from it.

I checked how to do it on some Youtube videos, but the problem is that the Cycles render settings disappeared as it is shown on the print screen.

I don't know why this happened, but when I open a different file or just create new,
everything is back to normal and there are all the settings (including "bake")

What is wrong with this file?

[image: Problem]

[image: without render settings]

[image: with render settings]

Comment: You could try to open your file with *Load UI* disabled. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149547/74827

Comment: Thank you! It helped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost the workspace menu...how to get it back?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149545/lost-the-workspace-menu-how-to-get-it-back)