# Is there any way to change ui to v2.80?

Tags: interface, versions

[image]

I downloaded a blender file and opened it but UI did not match V2.80. 
I guess that because the file have been made in old version its UI did not match V2.80.
I want change UI as V2.80 easily. 
Is there any way for me?

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-it-possible-to-use-the-startup-blend-ui-layout-in-older-files

Comment: @rjg Thanks for your good answers. But I wonder if there is any way to change UI after opening an old version file.

Comment: @Mr zak Thanks for your good answers. But I wonder if there is any way to change UI after opening an old version file.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @rjg Ok have a good day.

Comment: Yes changing UI without reopening file is probably impossible due to major differences between versions which leads to quite noticeable incompatibility