# Layout bugged after opening .blend file on windows instead of mac

Tags: interface

Multiple options overlapping so its hard to press some buttons.

all i did was sending the .blend file over discord from a mac to windows and this is how some places look.

[image]

How do i fix this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2152/110840 - check the bottom section of this answer for newer versions

Comment: @AllenSimpson I don't think that helps in this case.  3.0 seems to have a bug where it is overlapping things in the top left of the 3D Viewport.

Comment: It didnt seem to help no...