# How can i bring my Timeline back

Tags: animation, 3d-view, timeline

I accidently deleted my Timeline-Bar and  I dont know how to bring it back. As you can see its not above my Statusbar. I have already tried to drag it up but its not hidden it's deleted.
[image]

Comment: just click on a corner of your 3D view and drag in order to create a new window, then Shift F12 to have the Timeline (or Dope Sheet)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-it-possible-to-use-the-startup-blend-ui-layout-in-older-files