# I can't get the normal interface back

Tags: interface

[image]

I'm pretty new to Blender, so I'm not sure what happened, but I accidentally opened a bunch of windows. While I was trying to close them, this happened and I haven't been able to get back to normal since.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-it-possible-to-use-the-startup-blend-ui-layout-in-older-files

Comment: Press Ctrl Spacebar?