# How do I restore my Layouts?

Tags: interface

I accidentally closed my default and compositing screen layouts
could someone help me to get them back?

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts

Comment: Fixed it, use this: https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7209 follow the steps and you should be good