# (How) can we reset the 3D View?

Tags: interface

I am used to being able to reset my perspective/3D views.

In Fusion 360 e.g. you can click the cube's corner to get back "home". And I want the same functionality in Blender. (Not the cube...)

Is that possible in vanilla Blender or is there really just some [hackish add-on from 2014 made for Blender 2.69](https://developer.blender.org/T38718)???

[image]

Comment: None of them does what [this script executed in a Python console does.](https://pastebin.com/9N4R9Nsa) But I'd like to know whether that is now in 2017 possible without using scripting or an add-on...

Comment: I guess you already saw this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts. I understand, and may agree, but if you wish to be standard blender feature, you should issue a feature request (see https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact#Requesting_Features), this place is to only help with the existing...  another (ugly) workaround is to save the file, open a new one, then reopen the previous file without loading the ui...

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just asking, because I thought maybe I am just not seeing this now existing functionality...

Comment: Not sure what exactly would you like to do, maybe you can get kind of resetting by pressing Numpad period button and e.g. Numpad 1 to enter front ortho view. Then by clicking MMB to pan the view it will start from that position.