# I can't select objects and my bottom toolbar is missing

Tags: objects

[image]

It disappeared when i accidentally hid my bottom toolbar in the node editor, but when i clicked the transparnt "+" button to bring it back, all i got was this. Now, i cant select objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "bottom toolbar"? There isn't Node editor on the screenshot as you have 3D View Full screen layout selected, choose another one in the top of the window. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you return to the default view (the one you see when blender starts)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts)