# Interface changes with stock model files

Tags: interface

When I open a a Stock 3D model I downloaded, the entire interface changes. I see a "Default" layout option, but I don't see the stand "Layout" option at top of page. Is it possible that the model I have was created pre 2.8 & needs to be converted?

The model also does not have a Camera, & I can't see to find the "Add Camera" option that I see in basic tutorials.

I have attached screenshot of the UI as it appears with my stock model. Total Noob thanks you[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: How about this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts/855#855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the user interface saved on the file and use your default one.

Open blender.

Then use **File**>**Open** to select the file you want, click on the gear on the right side and uncheck the LoadUI box.

[image]

Comment: Perfect- thanks. As a Mac Guy, the Blender UI seems very PC-like -including this forum, where I don't see a "like" button in appreciation for your help.

Comment: This is not a "forum". The way to appreciate the posts of others is by up-voting or accepting an answer.  Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Also, if this isn't too "off topic": The 3D model I downloaded has a full set of image maps associated withe model, which was created in Blender. But the maps don't auto load when I open the model. Since it's a Blender file, is there a way to open the file with all image maps in place? Thanks again!

Comment: Again. **This is not a forum**. If you have additional questions ask them separately in new posts, not as a comment. One post per question is the rule. Please take the [tour] to understand how to make better use of this site.